# jPlayer stopped working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jplayer

**[Resolved]**
I was developing a [site](http://www.arso.hu) with jPlayer, and during development everything went fine. But recently our customers reported that the audio player doesn't work on mobile devices (which wasn't the case in development). It doesn't load the song info, all the fields stay uninitialized. I'm pretty sure that the plugin stops with some kind of error, but I'm unable to verify.

The uploaded files are OK, the relevant data are filled in - on desktop it is working fine.

The player is embedded in the homepage, just under the slider, the playlist is stored in the `div#jquery_jplayer_1` tag in the `data-playlist` property as escaped `JSON`. The relevant script is in `/templates/fooldal/fooldal.js@163`.

Unfortunately I am unable to debug on mobile (lack of devices and software), so if you could at least provide the JavaScript console info, even that would be much help!

If any additional info is required, I will update the question.

Thank you!

**Update:**
It is working fine with the default Android Browser (4.4) (not with chrome though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the priority of the audio formats in the `supplied` parameter.
i was using: `"m4a, oga, mp3"`
the correct order (to me at least) is: `"mp3, oga, m4a"`